# Jenkins 403 No valid crumb was included in the request

Tags: java, api, jenkins, post

I trying to make a post request to Jenkins after updating the `config.xml`.
I have passed crumb (`crumb: XXXX` and `crumbRequestField: XXXXX`) in the header but still showing error

> No valid crumb was included in the request

Please advise on how should i get rid of this error.

Comment: Can you share the details of your request. I have a similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63610834/trigger-jenkins-webhook-with-curl-fails-with-error-403-no-valid-crumb-was-includ

Answer (score 1):

Since we got no idea about you config, environment you are running or even full stack, **THIS IS MINE BEST BLIND SHOT**

Probably you are accessing jenkins by proxy server, please do following

- Go to "Global Security Settings"
- Check "Enables the Compatibilty Mode for proxies".
- Restart